# How do we stop all scheduled batch

Tags: scheduled-apex

We had scheduled batch jobs through developer console

```
System.schedule('Job1', '0 * * * * ?', new scheduledMerge());
System.schedule('Job2', '0 15 * * * ?', new scheduledMerge());
System.schedule('Job3', '0 30 * * * ?', new scheduledMerge());
System.schedule('Job4', '0 45 * * * ?', new scheduledMerge());
```

Now i want to stop these jobs from running every 15 mins. How can i stop these jobs? If i delete the jobs from Monitoring -> scheduled Jobs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this Apex code in Developer Console Execute Anonymous.

```
for (CronTrigger ct : [SELECT Id FROM CronTrigger]) {
    System.abortJob(ct.Id);
}
```

Comment: They may have schedulled jobs they do not wish to stop, did you consider that ?

Comment: I think that if they have some they will be able add some 
conditions to this query :)
In fact question was "How do we stop all scheduled batch"